# UTF8 & latin1 Character encoding in mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, latin1

I'm using PHP Version 5.5.12 & Mysql Version 5.1 . Is the character encoding important in Mysql? Default character encoding in my phpMyAdmin is 'latin1_swedish_ci'. I have some latex and pdf file conversions. I found that Latex would be happy about UTF8 encoding. What is the difference between these file conversions? should I make any changes in mysql queries? How to change latin1 to utf8?

I'm Looking forward to guys... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is important is so far as it determines what characters you can store. You cannot save "日本語" or other similar "exotic" characters in a `latin1` encoded column. If you may be required to do that, you'll have to choose an encoding for that column that can store those characters.

Note that there's also the *connection encoding*. Any client that connects to the database (e.g. phpmyadmin, your own PHP scripts, a database admin utility, any application etc.) implicitly or explicitly specifies a connection encoding, which denotes what encoding that client would like to receive. You can have a `latin1` encoded column and query data from it via a connection set to `utf8` and MySQL will convert the data on the fly and give you `utf8` encoded data nonetheless.